# How to print top 5 biggest repositories of Bitbucket

Tags: shell-script, rhel, disk-usage

I'm trying to write a shell script which will print the top 5 biggest repositories of Bitbucket and will present the Project name, Reposotry name, and its size.
repository config file example:

[bitbucket]
        project = TEST
        repository = customer_management_test

output of du command:

```
du -sh /bbhome/shared/data/repositories/* |sort -h |tail -5
2.0G    /bbhome/shared/data/repositories/1792
2.7G    /bbhome/shared/data/repositories/3517
3.0G    /bbhome/shared/data/repositories/2450
3.1G    /bbhome/shared/data/repositories/5703
4.4G    /bbhome/shared/data/repositories/2829
```

This the code I'm trying to run in REHL Bitbucket machine:

```
du -sh /bbhome/shared/data/repositories/* |sort -h |tail -5
while IFS= read -r line;do
        DIR=`echo $line | awk '{print$2}'`
        Rep=`cat $DIR/repository-config |grep 'project\|repo' |  tr '\n' ' '`
        Size=`echo $line | awk '{print $1}' `
        echo $Size $Rep
done
```

But I'm not getting the expected result.

Actual:

```
2.0G    /bbhome/shared/data/repositories/1792
2.7G    /bbhome/shared/data/repositories/3517
3.0G    /bbhome/shared/data/repositories/2450
3.1G    /bbhome/shared/data/repositories/5703
4.4G    /bbhome/shared/data/repositories/2829
```

Expected (one example for 1792):

```
2.0G   project = TEST  repository = customer_management_test
```

what's wrong with the syntax?

Comment: ... you're not actually piping the output of the `du` pipeline into the `while` loop?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Your first line runs `du -sh /bbhome/shared/data/repositories/* |sort -h |tail -5` and outputs the result via stdout to the terminal. Then your while loop loops over standard input (which is empty). 

You need another `|` connecting stdout from the pipeline to stdin of the loop.

Comment: can you write me the correct syntax to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first line runs `du -sh /bbhome/shared/data/repositories/* |sort -h |tail -5` and outputs the result via stdout to the terminal. Then your while loop loops over its standard input (which is empty).

You need another `|` connecting stdout from the pipeline to stdin of the loop:

```
du -sh /bbhome/shared/data/repositories/* |sort -h |tail -5 |
while IFS= read -r line; do

  <stuff with "$line">

done
```